# Flip book with HTML5 using Turnjs.com

Tags: jquery, html, turnjs

My client would like to integrate a flip book plugin - http://www.turnjs.com/ - in his site. In their official documentation, they said that it support all browsers and IOS, Android devices.

I checked the example URL - http://www.turnjs.com/samples/magazine/ in both browser and mobile devices. I am sure that it is working fine in all browser, but it is not working fine in mobile devices (mostly it is not working in Android). 
Issues
1 - Corner flip to go next page is not loading properly.
2 - In a screen 4 pages are loading for 2 pages (double page).
3 - After Zoom in, touch or frag on enlarged image gets Zoom in.

Being a licensed plugin it is not working in official example site.

Please let me know any ideas, to try to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my Samsung Galaxy S2, it works like a charm. Did you notice it says "Chrome for Android" ?

Comment: yes mate. It is working fine in Samsung Galaxy S3 with in Chrome browser. 
Please let me know for any other suggestions.
Thanks.